# I was trying to convert private key of an account to its public key but getting an error

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, cryptography, algorithm

code:

```
const accountFrom = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);
```

**getting error:**
throw new web3_errors_1.InvalidPrivateKeyError();
^

InvalidPrivateKeyError: Invalid Private Key, Not a valid string or uint8Array
at parseAndValidatePrivateKey

Answer (score 5):

Well, obviously it doesn't like your private key format.

I'm unsure what style private keys the function accepts. A typical private key is, for example, afdfd9c3d2095ef696594f6cedcae59e72dcd697e2a7521b1578140422a4f890 (taken from a google result). That's in hexadecimal, so you may need to prepend it with `0x`.

Basically, easiest just to try and see what format works. Or read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

privatekey=0xafdfd9c3d2095ef696594f6cedcae59e72dcd697e2a7521b1578140422a4f890
you have to add '0x' before your privatekey